# Clifford's theorem in Representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Let $V$ be an irreducible representation of a finite group $G$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$ (we can take any field in fact).

Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of $G$.

Look at $V$ as representation of $H$; it may not be irreducible, so take an $H$-irreducible subspace $W$ of $V$.

Next, consider subspaces $gW$.

It can be shown that $H$ acts on $gW$ (due to normality) irreducibly.

Now, take $\sum_{g\in G} gW$. Clearly, This is $G$-invariant subspace of $V$.

Since $V$ is irreducible, so $\sum_{g\in G} gW=V$.

**Question:** Can we say that $V$ is **equal to** direct sum of certain subspaces in $\sum_{g\in G} gW$?

Comment: This depends on your definition of direct sum. Normally, direct sums are defined externally, so that $U$ and $V$ are not subspaces of $U\oplus V$, but rather that there are injective maps from $U$ and $Y$ into $U\oplus V$. In this situation, $V$ is cannot be equal to a direct sum of its subspaces, as the direct sum is built externally.

Is your question that, or is it less pedantic, and you are just asking that if $V$ is a sum of some subspaces, then one may choose them so that $V$ is the (internal) direct sum of them? The answer to this is 'yes', by induction on the number of terms in a sum

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? A subset of $G$ which suffices for the sum over $gW$?